# Can not fire ajax on dom ready in IE9

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

i have some code that is supposed to be executed on dom ready without any click or any other actions.Below is the code:

```
if($.browser.msie){
        console.log("Using getJSON");
        $.getJSON(baseUrl,function(){
         alert('hi');
        });
    }else{
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.get(baseUrl, function(data){
                var boardNames = data;
                for (i = 0; i < boardNames.length; i++) {
                    $('.boardSelectmulti').append('<option value="' + boardNames[i].Board + '">' + boardNames[i].Text + '</option>');
                }
                console.log("done");
                $("#boardLinksi").hide();
                $(".boardSelectmulti").val(form_data.showmode);
                $(".boardSelectmulti").show();
            }, "json"); 
        },5000);
    }
  }
```

In other browsers works fine but in IE it never fires. I even tried a getJson call still no luck.Any idea why this might happen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you calling something different for IE?

Comment: I have had issues, in IE while printing console.log(). Have you tried it without the console.log() statements?

Answer (score 1):

Download AJAX Edition for [Free here](http://goo.gl/AM2qX). look at the Timeline View of IE and then FF, you'll easily spot where the differences are during page load and what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when the IE console (press F12) is open? Had that, and [DroidOS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1077485/droidos) pointed out that in IE the console object is undefined until the developer console has been opened at least once (see also [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361955/ie9-and-document-ready-dysfunct-except-when-developer-console-is-open/19362039?noredirect=1#comment28725446_19362039)).

Add this little code on top of your script:

```
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var console = console || {
        log: function() {},
        warn: function() {},
        error: function() {}
    };
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Make sure this comes BEFORE you include your JS files.