# IE9 and $(document).ready fail except when Developer Console is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a web application that works via Ajax handshake, where the handshake process is started when the original page loading has finished, by transmitting an ini command to the server application. This transmission is coded as the very last call within the $(document).ready(...) chain.

Works like a charm on all browsers, *except* IE9 (of course). IE10 is fine. Searching the Web and SO reveiled an abundance of information that were not helpful at all.

So I thought I'd open the developer console to check if any issues/errors were reported there as all my Ajax calls are wrapped in a try/catch where console.log outputs the error. And now, the funny thing is as soon as the developer console is open, it works flawlessly?

Seems to be some kind of a timing issue, then. I would hate it to have my ready chain deferred with a window.setTimeout() quirk.

Already tested:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).delay(500).doInitSequence(...)
    }
```

But that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have slipped up on this before.  It is easy to forget that the console object does not exist in IE unless the developer console is open.  All you need to do is to put in

```
var console = console || { log: function() {} };
```

right at the top of your script.  If you are using any of the other console functions you will have to put them in too.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't change the ill behaviour. But again, the stuff works when the console is OPEN so I doubt disabling the console could be of much help here?

Comment: We are not disabling the console - merely making sure that it is always available.  Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate the problem?  You can be almost certain that there are no murky timing issues - the kind of thing you are trying to do is very common place and always works, IE9, IE8, IE7...

Comment: Finally it worked, thanks - I just overlooked the fact that I'm also using console.warn() at a hidden place. I also had to add another HTTP header server-side forcing IE9 to use the latest document version - as I fo und out on another post IE likes to switch to Compatility Mode in Intranets... CRAP ;-)

Comment: Pretty much the first thing to do when you start scripting a new project is to test and put in the dummy console variable so you never fall foul of IE.  I have been there - the frustration of not understanding why the damn thing works only when the dev con is open is not something to be relived.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the `console` function for the Internet Explorer browser.

You can do it using conditional HTML comments plus overriding the console function:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         var console = { log: function() {} };
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```